# Slicing an array into several chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, foreach

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKDXH/9/).

How can I slice an array into several small arrays

```
var data = 
[ { number: '1' },
  { number: '2' },
  { number: '3' },
  { number: '4' },
  { number: '5' },
  { number: '6' },
  { number: '7' },
  { number: '8' },
  { number: '9' },
  { number: '10'}
            ];
```

and build a table for each of them?
    Example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Number</th><th>Number</th><th>Number</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Number</th><th>Number</th><th>Number</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 ........
```

The following code isn't working. The output is kind of a mess. As you can see in the fiddle, I can't access the key(number), and there are empty `<table></table>` tags in between the tables. Can anyone show me how to slice the array properly.

Code:

```
var data = [ { number: '1' },
  { number: '2' },
  { number: '3' },
  { number: '4' },
  { number: '5' },
  { number: '6' },
  { number: '7' },
  { number: '8' },
  { number: '9' },
  { number: '10'}
            ];
var chunks = [];
var item_html ="";
for (var i=0; i<data.length; ) {
    chunks.push(data.slice(i, i+=3));
}
for (var i=0; i<chunks.length; i++) {

     item_html += "<table><thead><tr>";

       (i, chunks[i].map(function(key,v){
       item_html += "<th>"+key+"</th>";
       })); 
     item_html += "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";

       (i, chunks[i].map(function(v){
       item_html += "<td>"+v.number+"</td>";
       })); 

     item_html += "</tr></tbody><table>";

}

$('#area').append(item_html)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incorrect headings are because you have the arguments to the iteration function in the wrong order in the first `.map()` call. The first argument is the value, the second argument is the key. It should be:

```
chunks[i].map(function (v, key) {
```

The empty tables are because of a typo. This line:

```
 item_html += "</tr></tbody><table>";
```

should be:

```
 item_html += "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

You were missing the `/` in `</table>`.

The corrected loop is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {

    item_html += "<table><thead><tr>";

    chunks[i].map(function (v, key) {
        item_html += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
    });
    item_html += "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";

    chunks[i].map(function (v) {
        item_html += "<td>" + v.number + "</td>";
    });

    item_html += "</tr></tbody></table>";

}
```

There was no point to the extra `(i, ...)` that you had around each call to `.map()`, so I removed it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PKDXH/13/)

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to get the key (number)? Your example can only get the index for `th`